# Show Div with jquery depending on list (php)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have read how to show/hide a div with jquery when there is a dropdown selection, built with "select" and options.

However, I am trying to figure out how to do this when I have the following code for a dropdown selection.

```
<?php echo $this->lists['catid']; ?>
```

This list displays a dropdown of options and I want for a specific option to show/hide a div.

The following code could work for a select with a specific id,"purpose", for example, but in my situation how I am supposed to use it?

```
$('#catid').on('change', function() {
  if ( this.value == '37');
  {
    $("#business").show();
  }
  else
  {
    $("#business").hide();
  }
});
})
```

This is the html of the output of the php code

[image: This is the html of the output of the php code]

Thank you

Comment: You might need to show what the parsed HTML looks like after the list has been loaded, because that will determine how you can select it with JQuery

Comment: Check out my answer, I believe it is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code should work for you

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  $('#catid').on('change', function() {
    let selected = $('#catid').val();
    if (selected == 37) {
      $("#business").show();
    } else {
      $("#business").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#business {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="catid">
  <option value="38">option 38(hide)</option>
  <option value="37">option 37(show)</option>
  <option value="39">option 39(hide)</option>
</select>
<div id="business">
  Division Visible!
</div>
```

Comment: I have the error "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function"

Comment: Do you haha a JQuery CDN included in your header?

Comment: There, I updated the code with a working snippet @giorgionasis

Comment: I included jQuery with CDN but there is again exception. Any typo error in your code maybe? https://imgur.com/a/XZEsNc7

Comment: Maybe try removing the "event" property... it is completely necessary, I don't really know what may be causing the problem, I tested it several times, here in the snippet and on my host and it seem to be working fine, Make sure if this part of the code is causing the problem, try running this single piece of code on a single document (first the css, then the html and lastly the JS) just for a test, if it is working, then it must be something else in your code causing the error

Comment: I am glad you found a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through each option and check the value. If the value is 37, then show that option (or any other div that you want to show):

```
$('#catid').on('change', function() {
    $('#catid option').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() === '37') {
            $(this).show()
        } else {
            $(this).hide()
        }
    })
})
```

**NOTE:** You can replace `$(this)` with the element/div that you want to show/hide if you want to show/hide something else.

Working JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/cfw0xgae/).

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not working. Do I need to add a css class to my div? https://imgur.com/a/FW88lMi

Comment: @giorgionasis Nope you don't have to add CSS. It could be that the JQuery is loading before the list has loaded, in which case you need to wrap all the JQuery in a `$(document).ready(function() {})`. Or it's because of the `.on('change', function())`. I have a working JSFiddle example here: https://jsfiddle.net/Ludolfyn/cfw0xgae/ . I'll update the answer to include this link. Let me know how it goes and if you get it fixed =)

Comment: @giorgionasis You also need to put "step3" in a variable or grab it with an ID like so: `$('#step3')`

Comment: I tried but still does not working. Also in your example, the dropdown does not change. https://imgur.com/a/onBCFjf

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#purpose').on('change', function() {   
    if (this.value == '37')
    { 
        $("#business").css('display','');
    }
    else
    {
        $("#business").css('display','none');
    }
});


 You also use this ans 

$('#purpose').on('change', function() {   
    if (this.value == '37')
    { 
        $("#business").show();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#business").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: I have not the id of the selector to use it. I have only the line of code of php with the list. #purpose is just an example

Comment: first you remove the semicolon after complete if statement